# How to embed SVG using SVGweb when jQuery is loaded (ie issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, svg

This is the svg I try to embed:

```
  <script type="image/svg+xml">
    <svg width="200" height="200"
         style="background-color: #D2B48C; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px;"
         id="embeddedSVG">
      <g id="myGroup" 
         fill="blue" 
         style="font-size: 18px; text-anchor: middle; font-family: serif;">
        <circle id="myCircle"
                cx="100" cy="75" r="50"
                stroke="firebrick"
                stroke-width="3" />
        <text x="100" y="155">Hello World</text>
        <text x="100" y="175">From Embedded SVG!</text>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <h1>Optional fallback content goes here!</h1>
  </noscript>
```

This works fine in ie6-8, SVGweb does:

```
<OBJECT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: #d2b48c; DISPLAY: block; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 5px; OVERFLOW: hidden" id=embeddedSVG_flash class=embedssvg name=embeddedSVG_flash codeBase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=10,0,0,0" classid=clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000 width=200 height=200><PARAM NAME="_cx" VALUE="5291"><PARAM NAME="_cy" VALUE="5291"><PARAM NAME="FlashVars" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="Movie" VALUE="js/svg.swf"><PARAM NAME="Src" VALUE="js/svg.swf"><PARAM NAME="WMode" VALUE="Window"><PARAM NAME="Play" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="Loop" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Quality" VALUE="High"><PARAM NAME="SAlign" VALUE="LT"><PARAM NAME="Menu" VALUE="-1"><PARAM NAME="Base" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="always"><PARAM NAME="Scale" VALUE="NoScale"><PARAM NAME="DeviceFont" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="EmbedMovie" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="BGColor" VALUE="D2B48C"><PARAM NAME="SWRemote" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="MovieData" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="SeamlessTabbing" VALUE="1"><PARAM NAME="Profile" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="ProfileAddress" VALUE=""><PARAM NAME="ProfilePort" VALUE="0"><PARAM NAME="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all"><PARAM NAME="AllowFullScreen" VALUE="false">
      <embed src="js/svg.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#d2b48c" 
width="200" height="200" id="embeddedSVG_flash" name="embeddedSVG_flash" swLiveConnect="true" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" FlashVars="uniqueId=embeddedSVG&sourceType=string&clipMode=both&debug=true&svgId=embeddedSVG" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" style="background-color: #d2b48c; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px;overflow: hidden;"
 class="embedssvg"  /></OBJECT><NOSCRIPT></NOSCRIPT>
```

but when I add jQuery:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The SVG does not render in ie6-8 (yet it does in chrome, ff, ...):

```
<script type="image/svg+xml">
<svg width="200" height="200" style="background-color: #D2B48C; display: block; margin-bottom: 5px;"              id="embeddedSVG">           
<g id="myGroup" fill="blue" style="font-size: 18px; text-anchor: middle; font-family: serif;">                <circle id="myCircle"  cx="100" cy="75" r="50" stroke="firebrick" stroke-width="3" />           
<text x="100" y="155">Hello World</text>             
<text x="100" y="175">From Embedded SVG!</text>           
</g>         
</svg>
</script>
```

I would expect SVGweb to work the same way, independent of whether jQuery is loaded or not.
How do I embed the SVG with SVGweb, so that it gets shown in ie6-8, while jQuery is loaded?

EDIT:

I may have found a solution. If I bring in jQuery before SVGweb it will work. Yet in the SVGweb manual it says:

> First, you must bring in the svg.js file into your HTML page as the
>   *first* script on your page, before all others

Comment: If you found a solution you should create an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including jQuery before SVGweb resolves the problem (as pointed out in my edit).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is no good because svgWeb will probably override jQuery functions like onload event handlers... Try updating svgWeb to latest release and place it back as first script tag in your head node.

@Mathias

Did you try this syntax? It worked for me.

```
mysvg.load = mysvg.onsvgload = function(){
    //Handler
}
```

Comment: could this be the answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11377473/load-event-not-firing-on-svg-with-svgweb ?

Comment: Might be, I'll answer there also then.

Comment: I just checked which svgweb version I used - Lurker 2011-02-03, this already seems to be the latest one. So this did not resolve my issue.